# book for metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, metric-spaces, book-recommendation

Can anybody suggest me a good book on Metric Spaces. Although I am not new to this subject, but want to polish my knowledge. I want a book which can clearly clear my basics. I want to start from the basics. Kindly suggest me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: **Just** about Metric Spaces??

Comment: @BabakS. yeah and all the higher topics related with it.

Comment: Most any good intro topology text will have the basics of metric spaces, maybe pseudometric spaces, and possibly uniform spaces.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89642/a-good-book-for-metric-spaces

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Copson E.T. Metric spaces. Cambridge University Press, London, 1968. v+143 pp.
- Kaplansky I. Set theory and metric spaces. Chelsea Publishing Co., New York, 1977. xii+140 pp.
- Searcóid M.Ó. Metric spaces. Springer-Verlag, London, 2007. xx+304 pp.

Comment: +1 for Copson E.T. Metric spaces and Kaplansky I. Set theory and metric spaces... I have not seen Searcóid M.Ó. Metric spaces..

Answer (score 11):

I suggest [Topology of Metric Spaces](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1842655833) by s. Kumaresan.

**In the preface:**

> The aim is to give a very streamlined development of a course in metric space topology emphasizing only the most useful concepts, concrete 
>   spaces and geometric ideas. To encourage the geometric thinking, I have 
>   chosen large number of examples which allow us to draw pictures and 
>   develop our intuition and draw conclusions, generate ideas for proofs. 
>   To this end, the book boasts of a lot of pictures. A secondary aim is 
>   to treat this as a preparatory ground for a general topology course and 
>   arm the reader with a repertory of examples.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest "Introductory Functional Analysis With Applications" By "Erwin Kreyszig". Its 1st Chapter gives a very nice introduction to Metric Spaces... Good Luck