# Good reference for metric topology

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, metric-spaces

I would like a "good" book (not really introductory, not too advanced with good theory and exercises) on metric topology covering the following topics:

> Metric spaces, open/closed sets, sequences, compactness, completeness, continuous functions and homeomorphisms, connectedness, product spaces, Baire category theorem, completeness of C[0, 1] and Lp spaces, Arzela-Ascoli theorem.

It may not be a full book but parts of books or lecture notes are also most welcome.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89642/a-good-book-for-metric-spaces), and the related ones. Munkres is very good. My favourite is James Dugundji, *Topology*.

Comment: Look at Kasriel's [**Undergraduate Topology**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486474194), which I discussed in [this 28 March 2006 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=4594852) archived at Math Forum.

Answer (score 3):

Look at *Metric Spaces* by E. T. Copson. It is volume 57 of the Cambridge Tracts in Mathematics series printed by Cambridge University Press. It should be available in paperback or hardcover. [Here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/metric-spaces/BA4E385AAC6E2F4206773B0818A318BC) is a link.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at *Intermediate Mathematical Analysis* by R.D. Bhatt.  It does not cover all the topics that you mentioned, but provides an excellent treatment (with lots of exercises) for topics upto and including connectedness in your list.

Answer (score 1):

Chapter 4: Metric and metrizable spaces.... in "General Topology" , by R. Engelking. You need to browse the Introduction to familiarize yourself with his notation (e.g. $\{x_i\}$ is a sequence), and be aware that for him, compact space means compact Hausdorff.... Chapter 3 is Compact spaces. It includes a beautiful short proof of the Stone-Weierstrass Theorem ( see 3.2.18 thru 3.2.21).... There is a wealth of extra material in the problems and exercises of this book.... But for $C[0,1], L^p,$ and Arzela-Ascoli, etc., I would suggest a text on functional analysis.