# Check the following statements.

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness, complete-spaces

Let $X=\{(x_1,x_2,\dots):x_i\in\Bbb{R}$ and finitely many $x_i$'s are non zero} and $d:X\times X\to\Bbb{R}$ be a metric on $X$ defined by $d(x,y)=\text{sup}_{i\in\Bbb{N}}|x_i-x_j|,x=(x_1,x_2,\dots),y=(y_1,y_2,\dots) $in $X$.

Consider the following statements:

- $(X,d)$ is complete metric spaces.
- The set $\{x\in X:d(\overline{0},x)\leq 1\}$ is compact, where $\overline{0}$is the zero elements of $X$.

I have to check that whether the statements are true or false.

consider the sequence $e_n,n\geq 1$, where $e_1=(\delta/2,0,0,...), e_2=(0,\delta/2,0,0,...)$ and so on.
clearly this sequence is Cauchy, but how to show that this question is not convergent? I am having difficulty for writing in my notebook.
help me with both statements.
Thanks|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of elements of $X$ defined by:

- $e_1=(1,0,0,0,0,\ldots)$;
- $e_2=\left(1,\frac12,0,0,0,\ldots\right)$;
- $e_3=\left(1,\frac12,\frac13,0,0,\ldots\right)$;

and so on. Then$$d(e_m,e_n)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }m=n\\\frac1{\min\{m,n\}+1}&\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$and therefore it is a Cauchy sequence. But it doesn't converge in $X$. If it did and if $e=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots)$ was it s limit, then, for each $m\in\Bbb N$, $a_m$ would be the limit of the sequence of the $m$<sup>th</sup> terms of the sequence $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, which means that $a_m=\frac1m$. But then $e\notin X$.

And $\left\{x\in X\,\middle|\,d\left(\overline0,x\right)\leqslant1\right\}$ is not compact, since it contains a sequence without a convergent subsequence, which is $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: $a_m=1/m$ converges to 0 as $n\to\infty$ that,s why $e\notin X$, also, I didn't get 
 disproving compactness.

Comment: The reason why $e\notin X$ is because it is false that $a_m\not0$ only for finitely many $m$'s. And on a compact space every sequence has a convergent subsequence. But any subsequence of $(e_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$, if it converges, must also converge to $e$, which does not belong to $X$. Therefore, that set has a sequence without convergent subsequences, and therefore it is not compact.

Comment: If possible, $e_n\to e=(a_1,a_2,...)$ then, for given $\epsilon>0$,  $|e_i-a_i|<\epsilon$, which is not true for large $i$. Am I right?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, since $e_i$ is a *sequence* and $a_i$ is a *number*

Comment: Could you please explain it for me? I am very confused.

Comment: Explain what? What's about my answer that you don't understand?

Comment: ohhh. I got it sir. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: One more thing Sir, Can you please refer me a book where I could find such type of problems?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89642/446262).